# How can I get weather icon from Yahoo API JSON?

Tags: javascript

I used a weather API in JavaScript from Yahoo, but there is no object in the response give me the weather icon, the code below show the JSON response.
How can I get the icon weather from API?

-

```
current_observation:

astronomy: {sunrise: "6:06 am", sunset: "7:11 pm"}

atmosphere: {humidity: 53, visibility: 10, pressure: 26.96, rising: 0}

condition: {text: "Clear", code: 31, temperature: 71}

pubDate: 1566507600

wind: {chill: 71, direction: 338, speed: 3.73}

__proto__: Object

forecasts: Array(10)
0: {day: "Fri", date: 1566507600, low: 66, high: 95, text: "Sunny", …}
1: {day: "Sat", date: 1566594000, low: 67, high: 92, text: "Sunny", …}
2: {day: "Sun", date: 1566680400, low: 67, high: 91, text: "Sunny", …}
3: {day: "Mon", date: 1566766800, low: 66, high: 91, text: "Sunny", …}
4: {day: "Tue", date: 1566853200, low: 65, high: 91, text: "Sunny", …}
5: {day: "Wed", date: 1566939600, low: 66, high: 91, text: "Sunny", …}
6: {day: "Thu", date: 1567026000, low: 68, high: 90, text: "Sunny", …}
7: {day: "Fri", date: 1567112400, low: 68, high: 90, text: "Sunny", …}
8: {day: "Sat", date: 1567198800, low: 68, high: 91, text: "Sunny", …}
9: {day: "Sun", date: 1567285200, low: 68, high: 90, text: "Sunny", …}

length: 10
__proto__: Array(0)

location:
city: "Amman"
country: "Jordan"
lat: 31.951771
long: 35.940449
region: " Amman"
timezone_id: "Asia/Amman"
woeid: 1968902
```

Comment: That is the object.  When you say "icon weather" what do you mean?

Comment: the name of the icon, I thought there is a link to yahoo I can get the icon based on its name, by src of the img tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the the Yahoo API over at https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/documentation.html#json-example, you don't.

You are supposed to use your own icons based on the `text` value inside `forecasts`.

ex:

```
{
    "forecasts":[
       {
          "day":"Tue",
          "date":1546934400,
          "low":52,
          "high":61,
          "text":"Rain",  // Take this value, and use your own image based on it.
          "code":12
       }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you.

I have another question, how can i send my region and city to api, how can i get them?

Comment: You should just need to send the `location` parameter with a comma separated list. Eg: `location=sunnyvale,ca` with `sunnyvale` being the city, and `ca` being the 2 character region code.

Comment: Fine.
but I don't want to fix the location var in parameters, I need that if the website is opened from any country, the jquery automatically get the current location ( city and region code ) then send them as a parameter to weather API.

Comment: You can indeed do this. You would either use the geolocation api to get aprox. coordinates, then translate that into city and region code, or you can use an IP address (may be less accurate) and translate that into a city and region code.